# Making a int with Math.random pick a new number when called

Tags: java

Right now my variables all are being rolled randomly but only once. How can I make it so that when the ints are called they roll a new number? All the stats are currently the same number. And everything is rolled only once.

```
int throwD4 = (int)(Math.random()*4+1);
int throwD6 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
int throwD8 = (int)(Math.random()*8+1);
int throwD10 = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);
int throwD12 = (int)(Math.random()*12+1);
int throwD20 = (int)(Math.random()*20+1);
int throwD100 = (int)(Math.random()*100+1);

int stat = (int)(throwD6 + throwD6 + throwD6);

String description = "A big strong dude with a cool longsword.";
String name = "Gladiator";

// stats
int STR = stat;
int DEX = stat;
int CON = stat;
int INT = stat;
int WIS = stat;
int CHA = stat;'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will certainly find that if you calculate a formula and then store it in a variable, then the variable will keep its value unless the formula is re-calculated and stored again in the variable. Accessing a variable's value doesn't re-run the formula that created it; the variable is just a dumb number that doesn't remember the formula. The fact that variables don't change unless you change them will be mighty handy over the lifecycle of your program.

Consider creating a method that returns you a random number, and every time you want a random, call the method:

```
public int throwDice(int howManySides){
  return (int)(Math.random()*(howManySides+1));
}
```

If you want more advice on how this might be used, add some contexts to your question as to how you're currently using e.g. throwD6

In essence, every time you think about writing `throwD6`, write `throwDice(6)` instead. For example:

```
//rolling a 6 kills the character
if(throwDice(6) == 6)
  character.Kill();
```